# How do I view the crash reason in a core dump?

Tags: multithreading, gdb, coredump, sigkill

I'm trying to analyze the core dump of one of my applications, but I'm not able to find the reason for the crash.

When I run `gdb binary file corefile` I see the following output:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
#0  0xfedcdf74 in _so_accept () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
(gdb)
```

But I am pretty sure that no one has executed `kill -9 <pid>`. With `info thread`, I can see all the threads launched by the application, but I can see nothing special about any thread.

By running `bt full` or `maint info sol-threads` I don't find anything that leads to the bug. I just see the stack trace for each thread without any information about the bug.

Finally I've found a thread which causes the kill signal.

```
#0  0xfedcebd4 in _lwp_kill () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xfed67bb8 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#2  0xfed429f8 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#3  0xff0684a8 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) () from /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#4  0xff0684f4 in std::terminate() () from /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#5  0xff068dd8 in __cxa_pure_virtual () from /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#6  0x00017f40 in A::method (this=0x2538d8) at A.cc:351
```

Class A inherits of an abstact class and in the line 351 a virtual function declared in the abstract class and defined in A is called. I don´t understand why if object A exists the call to the virtual base function crashes.

Comment: By using `thread apply all backtrace` I found a thread which called abort() function to raise kill signal. That helps me to analyze my code to investigate why a pure virtual function is called

Answer (score 1):

That `SIGKILL` could be caused by your app exceeding some [resource limit](http://www.unixarena.com/2012/07/solaris-10s-resource-management-and.html). Try to get the system log and see if there are any resource limit exceeded messages.

### References

- [Solaris Administration Guide: Resource Controls](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-1592/rmctrls-1/index.html)